# Heroku is giving me a 503 and I don't know why

Tags: node.js, heroku, server

So Heroku displays my front end fine, but when I make a call to my back end it only returns a 503 and I've had no luck with google finding an answer to my problem.

Here's my server

```
const restify = require('restify');
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const db = mongoose.connection
const router = require('./routes')
let PORT = process.env.PORT || process.env.VUE_APP_HOST

require('dotenv').config()

const server = restify.createServer({
    name: 'myapp',
    version: '1.0.0'
})

server.use(restify.plugins.acceptParser(server.acceptable))
server.use(restify.plugins.queryParser());
server.use(restify.plugins.bodyParser());
router.applyRoutes(server)
const uri = process.env.SERVER

mongoose.connect(uri, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useCreateIndex:true
    },
    () => console.log('Database connected'))

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function () {
    // we're connected!
    console.log('mongoose is connected')
})

server.get('/*', restify.plugins.serveStatic({
    directory: './dist',
    default: 'index.html',
  }));

server.listen(PORT, function () {
    console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);
});
```

Here is my log file

```
-----> Node.js app detected

-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false

-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  13.8.0
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

       Resolving node version 13.8.0...
       Downloading and installing node 13.8.0...
       Using default npm version: 6.13.6

-----> Restoring cache
       - node_modules

-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
       audited 19449 packages in 12.185s

       46 packages are looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details

       found 13 vulnerabilities (11 low, 2 moderate)
         run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

-----> Build
       Running build

       > quiz@0.1.0 build /tmp/build_1b1e8d06246614eaf4f8c73b7396ab26
       > vue-cli-service build


-  Building for production...
        WARNING  Compiled with 2 warnings9:31:34 PM

        warning  

       asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
       This can impact web performance.
       Assets: 
         css/chunk-vendors.f2de1e82.css (291 KiB)
         js/chunk-vendors.25e54ca6.js (249 KiB)

        warning  

       entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
       Entrypoints:
         app (550 KiB)
             css/chunk-vendors.f2de1e82.css
             js/chunk-vendors.25e54ca6.js
             css/app.83b7036f.css
             js/app.d2d7e1c2.js


         File                                    Size              Gzipped

         dist/js/chunk-vendors.25e54ca6.js       249.22 KiB        83.71 KiB
         dist/js/chunk-322ddd76.30a6d833.js      84.76 KiB         22.35 KiB
         dist/js/chunk-7a6727f2.c0631d11.js      21.09 KiB         6.60 KiB
         dist/js/chunk-fd105068.4e2b7450.js      20.63 KiB         5.84 KiB
         dist/js/chunk-5e9478d9.aa473c10.js      11.85 KiB         3.72 KiB
         dist/js/app.d2d7e1c2.js                 9.00 KiB          3.59 KiB
         dist/js/chunk-ef9ba634.75ba4138.js      4.23 KiB          1.78 KiB
         dist/js/chunk-20b8df38.167c1cfd.js      2.49 KiB          1.09 KiB
         dist/js/chunk-2d0ac3bd.a6df4124.js      2.18 KiB          1.05 KiB
         dist/js/chunk-2d20ec06.bc0797f6.js      1.77 KiB          0.92 KiB
         dist/js/chunk-beee9c80.2f37298d.js      1.37 KiB          0.64 KiB
         dist/js/chunk-2d230542.1693dee0.js      1.23 KiB          0.73 KiB
         dist/css/chunk-vendors.f2de1e82.css     291.44 KiB        32.34 KiB
         dist/css/chunk-fd105068.ee4c284f.css    35.29 KiB         4.49 KiB
         dist/css/chunk-322ddd76.fa9ee5dc.css    24.36 KiB         3.88 KiB
         dist/css/chunk-beee9c80.0670aa22.css    9.98 KiB          1.31 KiB
         dist/css/chunk-5e9478d9.6c52e948.css    8.44 KiB          1.71 KiB
         dist/css/chunk-7a6727f2.e044490b.css    3.71 KiB          1.00 KiB
         dist/css/chunk-20b8df38.c7315fda.css    0.89 KiB          0.35 KiB
         dist/css/app.83b7036f.css               0.03 KiB          0.05 KiB

         Images and other types of assets omitted.

        DONE  Build complete. The dist directory is ready to be deployed.
        INFO  Check out deployment instructions at https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html


-----> Caching build
       - node_modules

-----> Pruning devDependencies
       removed 1037 packages and audited 444 packages in 13.024s

       13 packages are looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details

       found 0 vulnerabilities


-----> Build succeeded!
-----> Discovering process types
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 50.5M
-----> Launching...
       Released v46
       https://quizzor.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

I cannot find any info on how to resolve this. When I run my server locally everything is fine, but Heroku just seems to hate me.

Comment: I can only see the static route. Where is the backend route you are talking about?

Comment: my node app server.js serves the static route. Heroku is supposed to access my Procfile and run npm start.

Comment: I am not understanding the question "So Heroku displays my front end fine" this basically means the front end is built and then node server is run. So you are able to access the fronend. So when it is showing 503

Comment: When a make a call to my backend. I try to use my login and submit to /sendtoken, but it just hangs until I get a 503. Everything runs just fine on my localhost, but Heroku doesn't respond with anything.

Answer (score 0):

I went to my mongodb atlas page and whitelisted every IP address. I then set my DB connection string to a variable within Heroku.